# c# различия между классом и типом?

Tags: c#, .net

Правильно ли я понимаю: каждый класс это совокупность типов, а каждый тип это либо класс либо структура?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Согласно [официальной спецификации языка](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/types.md#types), типы в C# делятся на

- **типы-значения** — это структуры и перечисления (`enum`),
- **ссылочные типы** — это классы, а также массивы, интерфейсы и делегаты,
- **типы-параметры** — это типы, являющиеся параметрами обобщённых классов и методов (они не являются ни типами-значениями, ни ссылочными типами, и живут по особым правилам), и
- **типы-указатели** (которые могут появляться лишь в `unsafe`-коде).

Каждый класс, в свою очередь, *определяет* структуру данных (не путать с `struct`!), содержащую

- **данные-члены**: константы и поля,
- **функции-члены**: методы, свойства, события, индексаторы, операторы, конструкторы объекта, деструкторы-финализаторы и статические конструкторы, и
- **вложенные типы**.

---

Таким образом:

1. Класс не есть совокупность типов, а лишь *определение* для структуры данных-экземпляра (он же объект) типа. Определение содержит именованные и неименованные данные-члены, функции-члены и вложенные типы.
2. Типами, кроме классов и структур, являются ещё и перечисления, массивы, интерфейсы, делегаты, типы-параметры и указатели.

Answer (score 2):

> каждый класс это совокупность типов

На уровне данных вы почти верно написали.

Есть три поправки.

1. Класс это не просто совокупность типов, а совокупность типов каждому из которых соответствует своё имя - поле класса.
2. Кроме того в классе могут быть определены функции, и метаинформация (смотрите атрибуты, рефлексия).
3. Каждой переменной, функции и самому классу соответсвуют свои модификаторы (доступа: public, private, protected, internal, есть ещё и другие, static, virtual, abstract...).

> а каждый тип это либо класс либо структура

тут вы верно написали, единственное что можно добавить что есть ещё делегаты, но на уровне реализации они тоже классы.